# Why doesn't closure work in these functions?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that closure doesn't work here? Isn't the `createTreeText()` function supposed to take the text variable from function where it's called? I know that I could pass it in parameters but why can't I do this through the closure?

```
function createTree(){
    var text = "example";
    text = createTreeText();
    console.log(text);
}

function createTreeText(){
    var newText = text.toUpperCase(); // error happens here
    return newText;
}

createTree();
```

Comment: Add your code as "code", not using image.

Comment: Why don't you just pass `text` as a parameter?

Comment: in the second function, it seems that `text` is an unknow variable, because it is defined in the first function only.

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't the createTreeText() function supposed to take the text variable from function where it's called

No, not at all. Functions close over the variables in scope where they're *created*, not where they're called. All functions get from where they're called is the information passed to them as arguments (and sometimes `this`, depending on how they're called and what kind of function they are).

This example may clarify, see comments:

```js
function wrapper() {
  var a = Math.random();
  
  function foo() {
    // `foo` closes over `a`, because `a` is in scope
    // where `foo` was created
    console.log("a = " + a);

    // `foo` does not close over `b`, because `b` is not in scope
    // where `foo` was created
    try {
      console.log("b = " + b); // throws ReferenceError
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error: " + String(e));
    }
  }
  
  function bar() {
    var b = Math.random();
    // Calling `foo` here does nothing to grant it access to `b`
    foo();
  }
  
  bar();
}

wrapper();
```

Answer (score 1):

createTreeText is not a closure. It doesn't have access to the scope of createTree. To make it work in your example using a closure, you could try this:

```
function createTree(){
     var createTreeText = function(){
         var newText = text.toUpperCase(); // error happens here
         return newText;
     }
     var text = "example";
     text = createTreeText();
     console.log(text);
   }

   createTree();
```

Answer (score 0):

Text is defined inside the scope of your first function; your second function has no reference to it at all.  You can solve this a few ways, but the easiest is to just pass it as a parameter:

```
function createTree(){
     var text = "example";
     text = createTreeText(text);
     console.log(text);
   }

   function createTreeText(text){
     var newText = text.toUpperCase(); // error happens here
     return newText;
   }
   createTree();
```